# Set-Cookie with sameSite=none and secure = true

Tags: express, cookies

I am having a project with frontend and expressjs backend, both are hosted in Vercel.

I am facing a problem with setting cookies,
if I am using

```
 app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "portfolio-cookie-session",
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET, //secret environment variable
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: getExpire(), //return date
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
  })
);
```

my frontend couldn't get any set-Cookies header,
[browserheader-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3gDx.png)

if I remove samesite and secure

```
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "portfolio-cookie-session",
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET, //secret environment variable
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: getExpire(), //return date
    // sameSite: "none", <---remove
    // secure: true, <---remove
  })
);
```

then browser can show the cookie header however, it will blocked cause samesite problem

[browserheader-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrRHA.png)

[warning-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSMZl.png)

**Thank you!**

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I am using https

Comment: Today it is best practice to always set the correct/intended samesite value. if you set it to none and using HTTPS, then you should not have any problems.

Comment: @ToreNestenius, I am using HTTPS and I should use samesit: none with secure , rigth? however it didnt set the cookie